# xfce4-screensaver change lock screen background

Tags: xfce, lock-screen, desktop-background, screensaver

I am using i3wm and I use `xfce4-screensaver` as my locker program.  The reason is that it feels familiar (dialogue to enter password and button to switch user).

`xfce4-screensaver` comes with 2 things: screensaver and lockscreen. I only care about the lock screen function so I turn off screensaver function.

The program works and whenever my laptop goes to sleep or even hibernate, I would move my touchpad or press a button and then I would get greeted with a familiar xfce login screen to enter my password and resume.

The only problem is that this defaults to a dull, blue background wallpaper.  This is not the wallpaper for my desktop, but the wallpaper when `xfce4-screensaver` runs.  So you have the blue wallpaper and the login box.

Is there a way to change this wallpaper for `xfce4-screensaver`?

Comment: You haven't provided your OS/release details; XFCE has had many internal changes as it completed its GTK2 -> GTK3 move, and without your OS/release details we cannot know your software stack details.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue with `xfce4-screensaver` was resolved by removing the desktop settings file `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-desktop.xml` for me.

The `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf` folder stores the settings of the `xfconf` daemon, which can be viewed with a gui using `xfce4-settings-editor`. The corruption of settings files may have happened during the update to version 4.16.0 of `xfce4-screensaver`.